# Can we override a New Standard button to launch a Flow in Salesforce?

Tags: visual-workflow

Is that possible to override New standard button to lunch a Flow in lightning? any advice will be helpful. Thanks

Comment: One of the options could be to make a Lightning Aura component and show a Flow inside id (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:flow/documentation)

Answer (score 1):

You can do the next:

1. Hide the standard button in all the layouts in appears using the steps in this [article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?language=en_US&type=5&id=sf.customizing_detail_page_buttons.htm)
2. Create a custom button that launches your screen flow
3. Add your custom button to all the layouts that you removed the standard button from.

I hope this helps.